# php pdo returning only one result set

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to php. I am making a call to store procedure that returns multiple result sets in MYSQL.

I can't seem to get PHP PDO to get the second result set. I only get the first. Any help is appreaciated

--more info

store procedure just makes to select statements like so

```
select * from Product where productId = id;
select url from Images where product_id = id;
```

PHP Code:

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=salamancju_HardGraft', $this->userName, $this->password);

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

        $stmt = $conn -> prepare('call GetProductById(:id)');
        $stmt->execute( array(':id' => $id));

        $results = array();

        do {
            $results = $results + $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

        echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: show the stored procedure, describe the array, show more detail

Comment: @Drew not sure what you mean describe the array? the array gets assigned by the  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); result from the tables is all varchar..

Comment: I was trying to keep your question alive, saw it had 4 close votes, and the hachet was coming down. Not like I put a ton of thought into it. But they closed it. If you do an [edit] in the question up top, and give more details, it sounds like it *could* be an interesting question, and maybe reopened

Comment: @Drew Seems like it's been reopened. You're up at bat now; show 'em how it's done ;-)

Comment: it would be nice if the OP gave YCS some feedback @Fred-ii-

Comment: Right... as if he's going to give feedback... back. *Fat chance 'o that*. His *after-sales service* department sucks, and should be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with stored procedures.
+ operator on arrays works not the way you think. Use [] instead:

```
    do {
        $results[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

will produce a nested array. If you want another format, please provide an example.

Save for this issue, your code is perfect. Most people who aren't new to PHP, won't be able to make it ever.